# Is the following innerHTML property a security risk compared to textContent?

Tags: javascript, html, security, innerhtml

I've seen a few articles (and posts on here) about the dangers of using .innerHTML in javascript.  The examples use quite complex pieces of code though and I can't work out if it's the supplementary code that is causing as much of the issue.

On my site, I have a simple click function on the menu that when clicked uses .innerHTML to change the word "menu" to "close", which is then toggled back to "menu" when clicked again (as well as toggling a CSS class of some simple style changes).

Is the code below still a security risk? And if so should I be using textContent instead? Or is this sort of thing only an issue if the innerHTML is directly linked to a database?

JS

```
var mobileMenu = false;

function toggleMobileMenu() {
    if (mobileMenu === false) {

       box.classList.add("active");
       button.innerHTML = "Close";
       mobileMenu = true;

    } else {

      box.classList.remove("active")
      button.innerHTML = "Menu";
      mobileMenu = false;

    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleMobileMenu();
}, false)
```

Comment: well if it is user input, they can add JavaScript to it...

Comment: If it is your input, there is not really a security issue unless you do not trust your own code. ;)

Comment: It's only an issue if part of the `innerHTML` comes from user input, but what reason do you have not to use `textContent`?

Comment: The reason for not using textContent is being relatively new to JS and I didn't know it existed.  So can i take it a click event is not classed as input? It has to be user input where they can actually type something (like an <input> form element etc)?

Comment: No, the origin of the thing you put into the page with innerHTML is what counts. In the example above, it's a static string like "Close", so it's fine. If it contained user input in any way (and there may be subtle ways), then it would be vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @gaborLengel  If you post that comment as an answer I'll happily mark it as correct so you get the bounty